# Why is my php form not being sent?

Tags: forms

I am new to Php and I am having a hard time setting up the form below. When I press send the form is not sent. I'd like the user to be sent on the same page. This is why I used $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] but apparently somethig isn't working properly. Could you help me out?

```
  <form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>" id="form_body_container">
                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/fun_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'>Q1 What do you do for fun?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q1" value="Play games"><p class='form_options'>Play games</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q1" value="Exercise"><p class='form_options'>Exercise</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q1" value="Go out"><p class='form_options'>Go out</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q1" value="Party"><p class='form_options'>Party</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/food_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'> Q2 Which food do you like?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q2" value="Lorem"><p class='form_options'>Starters</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q2" value="Lor"><p class='form_options'>Main courses</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q2" value="L"><p class='form_options'>Deserts</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q2" value="Lore"><p class='form_options'>Snacks</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/genie_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'>Q3 What do you wish?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q3" value="Lorem"><p class='form_options'>Money</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q3" value="Lor"><p class='form_options'>Become very smart</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q3" value="L"><p class='form_options'>Become immortal</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q3" value="Lore"><p class='form_options'>Possess super powers</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/love_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'>Q4 Your ideal relationship?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q4" value="Lorem"><p class='form_options'>Short but eventful</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q4" value="Lor"><p class='form_options'>Long but uneventful</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q4" value="L"><p class='form_options'>Not serious</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q4" value="Lore"><p class='form_options'>Being single</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/work_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'>Q5 Your ideal work situation?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q5" value="Lorem"><p class='form_options'>Making a lot of money</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q5" value="Lor"><p class='form_options'>Doing something you like</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q5" value="L"><p class='form_options'>Peaceful workplace</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q5" value="Lore"><p class='form_options'>Improving your skills</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/language_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'>Q6 What is your mother tongue?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q6" value="Lorem"><p class='form_options'>English</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q6" value="Lor"><p class='form_options'>French</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q6" value="L"><p class='form_options'>Chinese</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q6" value="Lore"><p class='form_options'>Other</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form_icon_container"><img src='img/icon/world_1200.png' class='icon_form iconq'></div>
                <div class='box_form'>
                    <div class="box_form_inside">
                        <p class='form_question_title'>Q7 Where do you come from?</p>
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q7" value="Lorem"><p class='form_options'>USA</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q7" value="Lor"><p class='form_options'>UK</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q7" value="L"><p class='form_options'>France</p><br class="br_form">
                        <input class="form_radios" type="radio" name="Q7" value="Lore"><p class='form_options'>Other</p>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <button type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id='button_form'>Submit</button>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a "submit" type button instead of your actual button.

**Your mistake**

You have a normal button  `<button type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id='button_form'>Submit</button>`

**Correction to make**

You must have a 'submit' type button, something like `<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="button_form" />` or `<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id='button_form'>Submit</button>` for example (note the type="submit")

Also, in HTML 5 the "action" attribute in the form is no longer required, it will send the form on the same page :) !

Answer (score 0):

> $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]

returns the path relative to the root directory try concatenating $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] with the root path.

if you are not sure what part is missing just echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]  on the top of webpage and see what part of the actual path is missing!